# Setting up a Windows shared computer for users without full terminal server

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I'm setting up a Windows 7 "resource computer" that will have applications installed like Visio 2013 and others that are used by my employees but not needed enough to buy individual licenses for everyone.

I don't have a need for a full blown terminal server for this (even with the current drawbacks), and have set it up as a resource in Exchange for scheduling purposes.

I've done a few local policy edits to enforce disconnects of idle sessions, printer drivers, and bandwidth control.

**My questions are**:

1. Is there a way to prevent a simple disconnect of a session (X/close) and require a logoff?
2. Any method for controlling the actual resource and time allotments short of manual intervention?  Meaning if a user books the resource in Exchange from 2pm-4pm right now there's nothing that forces them or at least prompts them that their session should be ending and they technically could keep using the shared computer past 4pm even if someone else is scheduled (thus requiring me to intervene like a parent).  I keep hoping for something similar to scheduling a "webex" or similar, but so far no luck.

Trying to search online for some of these issues I haven't found a great method for preventing disconnects.  Most involved programming or a script on the client side not the resource computer side.  For the second question, I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid this is still a license violation from [Microsoft Office License term](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/products/microsoft-software-license-agreement-FX103576343.aspx)

LICENSE RIGHTS AND MULTI USER SCENARIOS

1. Computer. In this agreement, "computer" means a hardware system (whether physical or virtual) with a storage device capable of running the software. A hardware partition or blade is considered to be a computer.
2. Multiple or pooled connections. You may not use hardware or software to multiplex or pool connections, or otherwise allow multiple users or multiple computers or devices to access or use the software indirectly through the licensed computer.
3. Use in a virtualized environment. If you use virtualization software, including client hyper-v, to create one or more virtual computers on a single computer hardware system, each virtual computer, and the physical computer, is considered a separate computer for purposes of this agreement. This license allows you to install only one copy of the software for use on one computer, whether that computer is physical or virtual. If you want to use the software on more than one computer, you must obtain separate copies of the software and a separate license for each copy. Content protected by digital rights management technology or other full-volume disk drive encryption technology may be less secure in a virtualized environment.
4. Remote access. The user that primarily uses the licensed computer is the "primary user." The primary user may access and use the software installed on the licensed device remotely from any other device, as long as the software installed on the licensed device is not being used non-remotely by another user simultaneously. As an exception, you may allow others to access the software simultaneously only to provide you with technical support.

Comment: Interesting.  I had even asked our MS rep about the idea of a library computer for shared use (similar to one at a real library or school) and they said it was ok.  Thanks for the info, I'll look into it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the licensing issue for a moment (which is valid and you should definitely take into consideration)...

1) No, there's no way for the server to know whether the user manually disconnected or was simply disconnected due to networking issues.  So the best you really have here is the existing idle session limits that force logoff.

2) There's no way I know of using in-box features to enforce scheduling like this.  It would require something 3rd party.  But it also doesn't sound like something terribly difficult to implement either.  The most likely scenario is that the machine is running some sort of agent that is aware of the scheduling data in Exchange and just keeps track of the time and forces logouts at the designated end times.